# Why my GridView cuts off at The End?

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

[image: Screenshoot of the cropped end of the GridView]

In the above picture, the item at the bottom is cut off like a red arrow.
Perhaps the size of the Gridview is the entire screen, and NavigationBottomView seems to cover part of the GridView. I want to specify the height of the GridView from the top of the screen to the top of the BottomNavigationView.

Below is my xml code.

1> Home screen xml code with NavigationBottomView(home.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="520dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="All Of "
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="196dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="G"
            android:textColor="#8e1414"
            android:textSize="60dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="IST"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="60dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2> Xml code using GridView(site_list.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".home"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:columnWidth="96dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center">
</GridView>
```

3> The xml code that designed the items in the GridView(list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        tools:text="Gistsite"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

4> The class that created the data type named Site(Site.java)

```
public class Site {
    private String msite_name;
    private String msite_url;
    private int msite_imagesource;

    public Site(String name, String url, int imagesource){
        msite_name = name;
        msite_url = url;
        msite_imagesource = imagesource;
    }

    public String getMsite_name() {
        return this.msite_name;
    }
    public String getMsite_url(){
        return this.msite_url;
    }
    public int getMsite_imagesource(){
        return this.msite_imagesource;
    }
}
```

5> SideAdapter code created by customizing an ArrayAdapter(SiteAdapter.java)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Site> {
    private Site currentSite;

    public SiteAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Site> sites){
        super(context,0,sites);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null){
            listItemView = 
 LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        }
        currentSite = getItem(position);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentSite.getMsite_imagesource());

        TextView name = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(currentSite.getMsite_name());

        return listItemView;
    } 
}
```

6> A fragment code indicating the capture screen attached above(OrganizationFragment.java)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OrganizationFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View organizationView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.site_list, null);
        final ArrayList<Site> organizations = new ArrayList<Site>();
        organizations.add(new Site("Gist 총학생회", "https://www.facebook.com/gistunion/",R.drawable.gistunion));
        organizations.add(new Site("Gist 동아리연합회", "https://www.facebook.com/gistclubunite/",R.drawable.clubnight));
        organizations.add(new Site("Gist 하우스", "https://www.facebook.com/GISTcollegeHOUSE/",R.drawable.gisthouse));
        organizations.add(new Site("Gist 문화행사위원회", "https://www.facebook.com/Moonhangwe/",R.drawable.moonhangwe));
        organizations.add(new Site("Gist 신문", "https://www.facebook.com/pg/GistSinmoon/posts/",R.drawable.gistnews));
        organizations.add(new Site("Gist 홍보대사", "http://blog.naver.com/PostList.nhn?blogId=gist1993&from=postList&categoryNo=28",R.drawable.gionnare));

        SiteAdapter organizationAdapter = new SiteAdapter(getActivity(), organizations);
        GridView gridViewO = 
(GridView)organizationView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridViewO.setAdapter(organizationAdapter);
     gridViewO.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
     {
            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Site site = organizations.get(position);
                    openWebPage(site.getMsite_url());
                }
        });
        return organizationView;
    }
    public void openWebPage(String url){
        Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent siteMove = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
        if(siteMove.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
            startActivity(siteMove);
    }
}
```

7> Java code representing the main home screen(home.java)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
             Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_officials:
                    selectedFragment = new OfficialFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_organizations:
                    selectedFragment = new OrganizationFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_circles:
                    selectedFragment = new CircleFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_projects:
                    selectedFragment = new ProjectFragment();
                    break;
             }
             return loadFragment(selectedFragment);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
 findViewById(R.id.navigation);

 navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }
    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager() 
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if you could read the questions I have made and give them some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its happening because you have set the FrameLayout height 520dp in xml

set the frameLayout height match and also use  `android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"`

try this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
       <OtherViews.../>
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The part I wanted was solved. Thank you. But why is it that the home screen is broken like the picture of the link shown above?